# Exchanging Scottish GBP In China

Tags: money, china, exchange

Seems like Scottish (Great British) Pounds are not exactly very welcomed around the world. HSBC here in China told me to take them back to Scotland with me. (Cheers!)

**How Can I Exchange Scottish GBP In China?** Can they even be exchanged anywhere for the matter? Seems no one wants to take them

Comment: Ha! I've seen places in England that refuse to take Scottish notes so I'm not sure you'll find someone there that would take them. I tried to see if any Scottish banks have a retail branch in China, I can see that RBS are there but I think it's more corporate offices. Hopefully someone here has an idea how to do it, failing that you just need to try multiple places and hope someone takes them ... maybe hotels or specialized ForEx places would accept them, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: Try to find somebody going to the UK (Scotland?) and exchange with them personally.

Comment: Echoing what @Max said.  I was working in Scotland and went straight to Tunisia on my next job, I found a scot in a tourist hotel who was happy to swap several of my Scottish notes for Bank of England ones.   And just before I left Tunisia I also did that for another tourist. Any forex exchanges at UK airports should be happy to swap at no charge. And if not any large high St bank in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, no major bank in China takes Scottish Pounds.

However, there are some private companies' posts online saying that they would exchange Scottish Pounds for CNY. For example, this one: http://www.xici.net/d199868781.htm (If you could read Chinese). Even if such company is reliable, I don't think they would offer a reasonable rate for you.

So I think it would be better if you just take them back to Scotland.

Answer (score 2):

As SpaceDog commented, even in the UK they are not universally recognised. The only consistently accepted British notes worldwide are from the Bank of England.

So either keep them for your next visit, or do a deal with a friend who is going to visit. This is actually what I do with most notes that aren't Euros or US Dollars, as outside the US and Europe I don't visit any country often enough, and I hate using airport exchange facilities (the rates are often terrible)